# Web Scraping using Macro and Task Scheduler

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, windows-task-scheduler

I wrote a macro to scrap data from a website at a specific time in the day. I used Windows Task Scheduler to activate the macro. Unfortunately, when the computer is idle or someone else is logged into the computer, the macro is unable to scrape the data. It runs the macro but it doesn't update the excel sheet with the data and its all blanks. My guess is that it is because IE is unable to render the webpage in the background or something like that. Does anyone know a workaround?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In order to ensure that the macro can always run you have two choices (as far as I can tell):

(1) Ensure that the user (under which the macro should be run) is always logged in. So, you'll either need a dedicated computer which is not used by anybody else or

(2) you will need to run the task scheduler on a server where several users can be logged in at the same time. For more information read this:
https://superuser.com/questions/43776/how-can-i-have-multiple-active-windows-sessions-simultaneously